# How to find number of days a range is within another range using SQL

Tags: sql, range

I'm trying to find a query that will give me the number of days a range is within another range. For example , lets say there's a table called dates

```
     UID    SmallRangeStart    smallRangeEnd     BigRangeStart     BigRangeEnd
       1     01 15 2016       01 20 2016        01 17 2016          02 30 2016
```

So I want to return 3 because the small range falls for 3 days within the big range ... is there a query that can do that?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: First make sure you're storing dates using a date data type

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And are those 4 columns in 1 row? Or is that distributed over 2 rows with 2 columns? Or 4 rows with 1 column? Also: `02 30 2016` is an invalid date. There is no 30th of February

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you want to use is that the overlap is zero if the two ranges do not intersect at all.  This would happen if the small range began and ended *before* the `BigRangeStart` or the small range began and ended *after* the `BigRangeEnd`.  Otherwise, if some overlap did occur, then you want to take the difference between the *larger* of the `SmallRangeStart` and `BigRangeStart` and the *smaller* of the `SmallRangeEnd` and `BigRangeEnd`.

Here is a MySQL solution:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SmallRangeEnd < BigRangeStart THEN 0
            WHEN SmallRangeStart > BigRangeEnd THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(GREATEST(SmallRangeStart, BigRangeStart),
                          LEAST(SmallRangeEnd, BigRangeEnd))
       END AS days_in_range
FROM yourTable
```

The query also doesn't change much when moving to SQL Server:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SmallRangeEnd < BigRangeStart THEN 0
            WHEN SmallRangeStart > BigRangeEnd THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(day,
                          CASE WHEN SmallRangeStart > BigRangeStart
                               THEN SmallRangeStart ELSE BigRangeStart END,
                          CASE WHEN SmallRangeEnd < BigRangeEnd
                               THEN SmallRangeEnd ELSE BigRangeEnd END)
       END AS days_in_range
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This worked! Any idea how to exclude Saturday and Sunday?

Answer (score 0):

For mysql database you can use datediff function

```
     select datediff('2016-09-15','2016-09-12')
```

this query  will return 3

for MSSQL database you can use (just subtraction)

```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2007-05-06 12:10:09','2007-05-07 12:10:09')
```

it will return 1

For oracle you can use

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
   TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff
```

FROM   dual

For PostgreSQL:you can use

```
 SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2011-12-31 01:00:00'::timestamp - '2011-12-29  23:00:00'::timestamp);
```

-- it will return: 1

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect fit for Postgres' range types:

Assuming you have four columns in a single row, first calculate the intersection of the two range, using:

```
daterange(smallrangestart, smallrangeend) * daterange(bigrangestart, bigrangeend) as overlap
```

This gives the overlap of the two ranges. From the new range you simply subtract the lower bound from the upper bound

upper(overlap) - lower(overlap);

So the whole statement would be:

```
select upper(daterange(smallrangestart, smallrangeend) * daterange(bigrangestart, bigrangeend)) - 
       lower(daterange(smallrangestart, smallrangeend) * daterange(bigrangestart, bigrangeend))
from the_table
where uid = 1;
```